# How to inteligently concat two strings so as to ignore duplicate substring

Tags: java, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate user input intelligently so that It removes duplicate substring in following way.

- uneasy + easyly = uneasyly
- concat + catalyst = concatalyst

Here is what I am trying to do, not able to figure out what's missing

```
public class Concater {
    public String concat(String s1, String s2) {

        String s = s1;
        int L = s2.length();
        while (L > 0) {
            String common = s2.substring(0, L);
            if (s1.endsWith(common)) {
                s = s1+common+s2.substring(L);
                break;
            }
            L--;
        }

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Concater c = new Concater();
        System.out.println(c.concat("uneasy", "easyly")+"|expected:uneasyly");
        System.out.println(c.concat("concat", "catalyst")+"|expected:concatalyst");
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
uneasyeasyly|expected:uneasyly
concatcatalyst|expected:concatalyst
```

***Is there a better way to do it?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is in the line

```
s = s1+common+s2.substring(L);
```

You are concatenating the whole of s1 plus the common part, which is already contained in s1. Try changing it to

```
s = s1+s2.substring(L);
```

and it should work (not tested, though).

Comment: gotta love when someone posts the exact same thing while you are writing up the answer...  Good job man :)

Comment: thanks can you please let me know if there is better way to do the concatenation?

Answer (score 4):

```
 s = s1+common+s2.substring(L);
```

The problem is that common is contained by s1 already. That's why you get two common strings.

However, you algorithm doesn't work under a more common case
   uneasyly + easytogo = uneasylytogo

Comment: do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: So close to what you got, you really need to try yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This line is your problem:

```
s = s1+common+s2.substring(L);
```

It should be:

```
s = s1+s2.substring(L);
```

---

Since you are asking for a better way to do this, iterating through the characters would probably be significantly faster:

```
int i = 0;
for ( s1Length = s1.length; i < s1.length(); i++ ) {
    if ( s1.charAt( i ) == s2.charAt( 0 ) {
        boolean matches = true;
        for ( int j = i, k = 0, remaining = s1.length - i; k < remaining; k++, j++ ) {
            if ( s1.charAt( j ) == s2.charAt( k ) ) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( matches ) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
s = s1.substring( 0, i ) + s2;
```

*Note that this is untested, but gets the algo across...*

---

Just thought of one more thing, if you compared the length of 1 vs the length of 2 before doing this you could make it more efficient by choosing which to iterate in the outer loop.  If for instance s2 is shorter than s1, you could see a performance improvement (however slight) by iterating backwards from the end of the 2 strings with s2 in the outter loop.  Probably not worth it, but you asked for more suggestions...

Comment: @hiran, I added a suggested algo for you to check out.